# Earth and moon orbit arround the sun in pygame with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make solar system only has two properties that the earth moves around the sun and the moon moves around the earth continuously in pygame with python code. Here is my code:

```
import sys, random, math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
black = 0, 0, 0
white = 255, 255, 255
grey = 125, 125, 125
red = 255, 0, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255
width = 500
height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
screen.fill(white)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 15)
def rotate2D(x,y,angle):
    angle = 0.0174532925*angle
    x_r = x*math.cos(angle) - y*math.sin(angle)
    y_r = x*math.sin(angle) + y*math.cos(angle)
    return (x_r, y_r)
def translate2D(x,y,tx,ty):
    x_t = x+tx
    y_t = y+ty
    return (x_t, y_t)
def show_FPS():
    text = font.render('day = ' + '{:.2f}'.format(day) + ', ' + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + ' FPS', True, black, white)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.bottomright = screen.get_rect().bottomright
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
sun_radius = 70
earth_radius = 15
ex = 0
ey = 0
moon_radius = 10
mx = 0
my = 0
sun2earth_dis = 200
moon2earth_dis = 90
sun2earth_orbit = 0
moon2earth_orbit = 0
day = 0
flag = 1
while flag:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            flag = 0
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            flag = 0
    screen.fill(white)
    day = day+0.2
    sun2earth_orbit = -(day*360.0)/365
    moon2earth_orbit = -(day*360.0)/27
    ex_, ey_ = translate2D(ex, ey, sun2earth_dis, 0)
    ex_, ey_ = translate2D(ex_, ey_, width/2, height/2) 
    mx_, my_ = translate2D(mx, my, moon2earth_dis, 0)
    mx_, my_ = rotate2D(mx_, my_, moon2earth_orbit)
    mx_, my_ = translate2D(mx_, my_, width/2, height/2)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (int(width/2), int(height/2)), sun_radius)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, (int(ex_), int(ey_)), earth_radius)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (int(mx_), int(my_)), moon_radius)
    show_FPS()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

In this code, the earth moves around the sun. its looks fine. now i want to moves moon around the earth which continuously moves around the earth and sun. i set the earth moves sun in 365 days in a full round, in moon it will be moves around the earth in 27 days.

For Details (That's original idea i want to develop):

orbital speed:
earth around the sun in 365 days,
moon around the sun in 27 days,

spinning speed:
the sun 1 round in 30 days, 
earth 1 round in i day,
moon always facing the earth
I have done this. But how moon moves around the sun the idea is still not clear to me.

Comment: You might need to look into learning some [matrix math](http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Transformation_Matrix) in this case! The secret is to recognize that you can combine multiple rotations/scales/transformations together simply by multiplying multiple individual transformation matrices. I can elaborate on this in an answer if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try calculating the coordinates of moon with Earth at [0, 0] and then add it to current coordinates of Earth.

Comment: can you explain more please.

Comment: So, ignore the sun for a moment and considee model of only earth at the center. In this case you would describe change of position for the moon in regards to earth at [0,0]. If you do not take account any gravitational forces of sun on moon, which it seems you do not, and only plan on describing it as a simple model, then all you want to do is 1.) Calculate the position of moon as if the earth was in the center [0,0] and 2.) Move it to the current coordinates (add earths actual [x,y] to it).

Comment: And to somewhat expand what @CodeSurgeon said. For system this simple you do not need matrixes. They actually overcomplicate such a simple system. But if you ever plan on describing more complex systems you should look into it. Not only to they allow for easier description, but are also faster in terms of calculation speed, and especially if you can use vector processors which are designed for fast computations on vectors and matrixes. This allows for fast calculation that you wouldn't even be able to commonly do in reasonable time.